# Skype crashes with external exception c00001d when opening video settings or making video call

Tags: windows-7, video, crash, skype, webcam

When I try to make a video call or open the video settings windows, skype crashes with generic message "Skype has stopped working". And then a message box appears:

```
External exception c00001d
```

Skype works perfectly otherwise (messages, voice calls).

Webcam works perfectly with any other software (amcap, vlc).

Webcam: Canyon CNR-FWC113, latest drivers installed from manufacturer's website.
Skype version: Latest (7.10.0.101)
Windows: Win7, latest updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might sound hilarious, but plugging the camera to rear USB ports instead of front ones fixed this.